# How to have an invisible start up form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an application that is a part of a solution of projects. In this project I would like for it to start up form to be invisible, but still have a notification icon in the tray visible for this form.

I know that adding `me.hide` into the `form_load` doesn't work. I tried adding a module that instantiates the startup form and I set it as the startup object. Although that didn't work either. I am running out of ideas to have this form invisible. Could anyone help out? I am using VB.NET.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Paste this in your form code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

The way that works is that the very first request to show the form, done by the Application class, this code overrides the Visible property back to False.  The form will behave as normal after this, you can call Show() to make it visible and Close() to close it, even when it was never visible.  Note that the Load event doesn't fire until you show it so be sure to move any code in your event handler for it, if any, to the constructor or this override.

Comment: Thanks it works. I have one question though. I have a splash screen set on my project, an now since the main form doesn't "load" like it normally would, it doesn't close off the splash screen. I figure the way around it would be to add splashscreen.close() into the main forms overide. Although I get a illegal cross thread error. Would it be okay to set check for illegalcrossthreadcalls in this to false? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Ugh.  The splash screen closes when the main form's Load event fires.  As I documented, that doesn't happen until you call Show().  You can't have it both ways.  Only use a splash screen when the startup of your program is delayed.

Comment: This is a perfect Q&A. I had the same problem and this works exactly as I wanted. Now the form is not shown even for some milliseconds. Thank you.

Comment: Also there is a very good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15831283/2721611) for managing vb.net application forms and context at startup by calling `sub main()`.

Comment: Great solution. Most effective for me. All the Opacity, Hide, minimize options all resulted in a brief flash before operation. This ensures no visibility at all. You just have to be mindful of what you have under mybase.load, possibly sub it + call from above override. Other option is me.show() in the override.

Comment: Perfect for a situation where I create some threads in the form's constructor. I show the form only when all threads are done. So many years using NET and never knew about this override. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Put this in the form's Shown event

```
Me.Visible = False
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my purpose, as I have many other things that launched on Start-up that don't work with the accepted solution.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to set the opacity of the form to 0%. When you want it to appear, set it back to 100%

Comment: This solves my problem. Call `Me.Visible=false` in `Shown` event will cause the display looks odd. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way that I've found to do this.

Set the form properties with

```
ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Then in the form's constructor add

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

This is very easy to implement and works with no flicker.  In my case I also use a NotifyIcon to access the program from the notification tray and just set

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
Show()
BringToFront()
```

In the Notify_MouseClick event handler.

To hide the form again after displaying it, just minimizing again doesn't quite do the job. In my case I use the Form_Closing event and just hide the form.

```
Hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Me.Opacity = 0` to hide the form on load event.

Then use the following code in the form.Shown event

```
Me.Hide()
Me.Opacity = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw out a completely different approach, have you considered **not** using the overload of `Application.Run()` that takes (and automatically shows) a `Form`?  If you use the one that passes in an `ApplicationContext` (or more tyoically, your own subclass of `ApplicationContext`) then you can choose what your behavior is.  See here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901

Comment: And if it were me, I wouldn't create the form at all on startup.  Your custom ApplicationContext can create and listen for events from the tray notification component just fine.  Then you only need to create a form when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub New()
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(False)
End Sub
```