# Supressing a form with button while taking a screenshot on VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and I am trying to create a screenshot capture on button click application using VB.net.
When I am trying to take a screenshot using a button click on a form in VB.net, the form is appearing in the screenshot. When I tried to hide the form using the me.hide or Me.visible=false or me.sendtoback, the form is still appearing in the screenshot. The best part is sendtoback is working in one system, but not properly in another.

Below is the code for button click
count is global integer with value 1 initialized at beginning

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    clickpicfull()

    'PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Bulusu\Desktop\Screenshots\" & count & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(picspath & "\" & count & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    count = count + 1

    Me.Controls("label1").Text = "No of Screenshots: " & count - 1
    ' MsgBox(count)

End Sub
```

and below is the code for taking the screenshot

```
Public Sub clickpicfull()
    If count = 1 Then
        Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(438, 300)
    End If
    Me.SendToBack()
    Me.Hide()
    Me.Opacity = 0
    Form2.Hide()

    Dim area As Rectangle
    Dim capture As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    capture = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(capture)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, area.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    PictureBox1.Image = capture
    Me.Opacity = 100
    Me.Show()
    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: An issue on old Windows versions like XP or when Aero is disabled.  Using Opacity is a workaround but you are not using it correctly.   Set the Opacity property to 99 in the designer.  In your code, change it back to 0.99, not 100.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393715/how-to-have-an-invisible-start-up-form)?

Comment: Thanks Hans and Josh for the reply

Comment: Thanks Hans and Josh for the reply. @Josh on trying your override function, I am unable to view the form. I guess that is for hiding the form while opening the application and basically like me.hide() while opening. Please let me know if there is any other way to implement your code for my requirement

Comment: @HansPassant tried with your suggestion and it is working perfectly now. Adding to that, came to know one from my friends that adding thread.sleep(500) will enable me to use me.hide as well.

Comment: Hmya, 500 is just a guess of course.  The windows you overlapped have to redraw themselves, how long that takes is highly unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HansPassant by changing the opacity values as below gave me the desired result

Putting default opacity of the form to 99 in the designer and swapping
the opacity between 0 and 0.99 using the below

Me.Opacity = 0 and Me.Opacity = 0.99

```
`Public Sub clickpicfull()
    ' Me.Hide()                 'solution 1
    'Thread.Sleep(500)          'solution 1
    Me.Opacity = 0              'solution 2
    Form2.Hide()

    Dim area As Rectangle
    Dim capture As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    capture = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(capture)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, area.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    PictureBox1.Image = capture
    Me.Opacity = 0.99           'solution 2
    'Me.Show()                  'solution 1

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the system handle the events. When you call most of the methods on the Window class, you might want to wait for things to settle down. Try adding the delay using [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157891(v=vs.110).aspx) (be sure to read the documentation for any issues that may happen such as unintended event handlers getting called). Also, opacity should range from 0.0 to 1.0. 100% opaque is set as 1.0.

```
Public Sub clickpicfull()
If count = 1 Then
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(438, 300)
End If
Me.SendToBack()
Me.Hide()
Me.Opacity = 0
Form2.Hide()
Application.DoEvents()

Dim area As Rectangle
Dim capture As System.Drawing.Bitmap
Dim graph As Graphics
area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
capture = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
graph = Graphics.FromImage(capture)
graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, area.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

PictureBox1.Image = capture
Me.Opacity = 1.0
Me.Show()
Me.BringToFront()
```

End Sub